# voxelize VTU file in python

Tags: python, pixel, vtk

How can I voxilize the attached [vtk](/questions/tagged/vtk) unstractured file (`VTU`) using [python](/questions/tagged/python)? Ideally I want to define the region `(xmin=-9, xmax=9)` and `(ymin=-9, ymax=9)` and the number of pixels (e.g `(256,256)` in each direction) and extract that region onto the pixel grid and store in file (with hollow regions filled).

[VTUfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FvTTup_lZZWCxexYSz-QM3oBG5ljGw07)

here is how I read the file into polyData

```
import vtk

# Read the source file.
reader = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName("internal.vtu")
reader.Update()  
polydata = reader.GetOutput()
```

How can I convert the `polydata` now into the file with above details?

Thanks

Comment: @stovfl Thanks but that post is different. Here I am dealing with an unstructured mesh VTK file. My question also includes defining the region to extract the data from the vtu file and also the gving pixel resolution. It is more on voxelization (but in 2D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, I had a similar problem using [vtkplotter](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter) recently which might turn useful to you:

```py
from vtkplotter import *
import numpy as np

g = load('internal.vtu')
g.pointColors("p", cmap='terrain')

pts = g.points()
field = g.getPointArray('U')
ars = Arrows(pts-field/5, pts+field/5, c='k')

zpr = np.linspace(-15,15, num=25)
probes = np.c_[np.zeros_like(zpr)-10, np.zeros_like(zpr), zpr]

str_lns = streamLines(g, probes, activeVectors='U', maxPropagation=60, lw=2)
str_lns.pointColors(cmap='jet')
str_lns.GetProperty().LightingOff()
str_lns.mapper().SetResolveCoincidentTopologyToPolygonOffset()

show(g, ars, Points(probes), str_lns, elevation=90)

vol = interpolateToVolume(g, dims=(50,2,50), bounds=(-9,9,0,0,-9,9))
# vol.imagedata() # retrieves the vtkImageData obj
lego = vol.legosurface(cmap='terrain')

show(lego, newPlotter=True, elevation=90)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer was what I was after. Many thanks man. just how can I write the vol object into numpy array? This would be (50,2,50,4) (3 would be Ux, Uy,Uz,p)?

Comment: You can do it with print(vol.getPointArray()) and save it with e.g. write(vol,'name.vti')

Answer (score 2):

## Answer in pure VTK

You should use the `vtkResampleToImage` filter. https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkResampleToImage.html (the doc is c++ oriented but the methods are the same in python)

And for your information, the output of your reader is a vtkUnstructuredGrid object. A polydata is another kind of vtk data set for 3D surface object. See here for more : https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/VTKFileFormats/#dataset-format

```
import vtk

reader = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName("/home/nicolas/Tmp/discourse/internal.vtu")
reader.Update()

toImage = vtk.vtkResampleToImage()
toImage.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
toImage.SetUseInputBounds(False)
toImage.SetSamplingDimensions(256,1,256)
toImage.SetSamplingBounds(-9, 9, -0.1, 0, -9, 9)
toImage.Update()

imageData = toImage.GetOutput()
imageData.GetPointData().SetActiveScalars("U")

# Visualization
mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(toImage.GetOutputPort())
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()

# Write to file 
writer = vtk.vtkXMLImageDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName(filename)
writer.SetInputData(imageData)
writer.Write()
```

[image]

Comment: interestingly I get "Floating point exception" from the vtkResampleToImage filter. If i set SetSamplingDimensions(256,2,256) it works and i dont get the red pixels in the image you show. Any ideas of why is that?

Comment: which version of VTK ? I don't have this with the fresh 9.0.0

Comment: I've got version 8.1.2